# How to properly truncate a double

Tags: java, precision, truncate

How to properly truncate a double in Java, so for example 1.99999999999999999 is always truncated to 1 and not rounded upto 2 as is the case in the sample below.

```
    double d1 = 1.999999999999999999;
    double d2 = 1.0; 
    long i1 = (long)Math.floor(d1);
    long i2 = (long)Math.floor(d2);
    System.out.println("i1="+i1 + " i2="+i2); //i1 == 2
```

Running sample here: http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/42603

### Solution

Use `BigDecimal` which has arbitary precision

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("0.9999999999999999999999999999");
bd = bd.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN); //truncate
```

Comment: [`Math.round()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29)

Comment: You'll want `BigDecimal` for this kind of numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`1.99999999999999999` is not rounded up to `2`, it *is* `2`.

```
System.out.println(1.999999999999999999);      // 2
System.out.println(1.999999999999999999 == 2); // true
```

Floating-point numbers aren't infinitely precise. There aren't enough bits in the storage format Java uses (IEEE `double`) to distinguish between `1.999999999999999999` and `2`.

If you need more accuracy than that, try a different number format, such as `BigDecimal`.

Comment: BigDecimal doesn't seem to be able to handle this much precision either - see here http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/42606

Comment: @volting BigDecimal can distinguish new BigDecimal("1.999999999999999999") from two, represent it exactly, and print it correctly. The referenced article used Double, rather than BigDecimal, to parse the string, so that the new BigDecimal could only have a value that could be exactly represented in double.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `d1` has too much precision to be expressed as a double.

If you print `d1` directly to System.out you get `2.0`.

So any call to `floor` or `round` has no effect.

If you need such a precision you should go for `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the examples are explained [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_round.htm)

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29)

```
double d1 = 1.999999999999999999;
double d2 = 1.0; 
long i1 = (long)Math.round(d1);
long i2 = (long)Math.floor(d2);

System.out.println("i1="+i1 + " i2="+i2);
```

Then the output will be

```
i1=2 i2=1
```

Comment: He doesn't want 2 and 1, he wants 1 and 1.

Comment: He's just giving an explanation as to what they do instead of just giving a straight out answer. No need for the down vote

Comment: heh, it's not answering the question.

Comment: @redFIVE But it's not answering the question, and is generally misleading. The code in the question is already what OP wants to do (and it's correct by the way), it's just not working as expected. This does something else entirely.